# Prevent emacs desktop save from holding onto theme elements

Tags: emacs

I've been having an odd interaction between desktop save and the theme system.  I noticed while trying to set up a custom theme that certain elements weren't matching the theme values.  Things like the background color or the cursor color were holding onto their previous values.

Finally, I traced it back to my `.emacs.desktop` file, an excerpt:

```
;; Global section:
(setq (foreground-color . "#93a1a1") (background-color . "#002b36") 
(mouse-color . "black") (border-color . "black") (screen-gamma) (line-spacing) 
(left-fringe . 10) (right-fringe . 11) (alpha) (menu-bar-lines . 1) 
(tool-bar-lines . 0) (title) (fullscreen) (icon-type) (auto-raise) (auto-lower) 
(cursor-type . box) (scroll-bar-width . 17) (horizontal-scroll-bars . t) 
(display-type . color) (background-mode . dark) (cursor-color . "#fdf6e3")
```

Is there some way to make it not do that?  I like the desktop feature for preserving my open files and window position, but I don't want it to keep all that style information.  I've hunted around and tried setting `desktop-globals-to-save` and other variables but nothing seems to do it.

Comment: If I were to make a guess, I would probably start with looking at `desktop-save-frameset`, which calls `frameset-save`.  There is no function that I am aware of which adds the parameter `desktop-dont-save`, but it looks like the doc-string of `desktop-save-frameset` makes a reference to a test of whether it has a value -- these are cons cells.  It is possible to strip certain elements of the list returned by `frameset-save` -- e.g., if the car of the cons cell is `mouse-color`.

Comment: I agree with @lawlist, these look like frame parameters.  You might like to `M-x report--emacs-bug` to see what the experts on frameset and desktop.el can do about it.

Answer (score 2):

Just hit this. You'll need to update `frameset-filter-alist` with the things that you do not want to save. For example:

```
(push '(foreground-color . :never) frameset-filter-alist)
(push '(background-color . :never) frameset-filter-alist)
(push '(font . :never) frameset-filter-alist)
(push '(cursor-color . :never) frameset-filter-alist)
(push '(background-mode . :never) frameset-filter-alist)
(push '(ns-appearance . :never) frameset-filter-alist)
(push '(background-mode . :never) frameset-filter-alist)
```

Answer (score 1):

This gist worked for me:

[desktop-load-theme.el](https://gist.github.com/vividsnow/0609b55bd684d325e7cb)

```
(desktop-save-mode)
(add-to-list 'desktop-globals-to-save 'custom-enabled-themes)
(defun desktop-load-theme () "load custom theme" (interactive)
  (dolist (th custom-enabled-themes) (load-theme th)))
(add-hook 'desktop-after-read-hook 'desktop-load-theme)
```

But it doesn't prevent the desktop-save-mode from saving the theme in the .desktop file, instead it restores the theme after loading the desktop.  For me its a good joice.

Answer (score 0):

Open `.desktop` file, the color theme configurations saved in frame fields, this can avoided by set `desktop-restore-frames` to `nil`.

For more information, see `desktop-restore-frames` documentation:

> When non-nil, save and restore the frame and window configuration.

Complete configurations:

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(desktop-save t)
 '(desktop-restore-frames nil)
 '(desktop-path (list "~/.emacs.d/"))
 '(desktop-dirname "~/.emacs.d/"))
(desktop-save-mode 1)
```

Comment: This is a bit cryptic.  Can you add a sentence or two to explain how to use this to solve the problem?  [from review](https://superuser.com/review/low-quality-posts/729777)

Comment: @fixer1234 I add some explain, please take a look